# RNCryptor and Python server

Tags: python, ios, encryption, rncryptor

I'm using RNCryptor to encrypt NSData on iOS and send it to a Python server. So far, so right. My problem comes when I try decrypt NSData on server side.

RNCryptor embeds all relevant data in encrypted header, but I can not get the IV in the server side to decrypt data received.

Any idea?

**Configuration:**
*iOS 5.0 with RNCryptor / 
Python + Tornado Web Server*

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's not encrypted, it just prepends header info to the NSData. If your not using password based encryption, i think you need to skip 2 bytes, and then read in the length of the IV to get the iv. But based on various settings headers length conditionally changes see full details:

- [Data Format](https://github.com/rnapier/RNCryptor/wiki/Data-Format)
- [RNCryptor Header Reading Code](https://github.com/rnapier/RNCryptor/blob/master/RNCryptor/RNDecryptor.m#L153)